# Find volume of region bounded by plane, bounded by $y^2 = 1 - x$ and $x = -1$, and parabolic cylinder, $z = 1 - x^2$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume

Question:

Let $R$ denote the finite plane region on the $xy$-plane bounded by the line $x = -1$ and the parabola $y^2 = 1 - x$. Let $D$ denote the solid region under the surface of the parabolic cylinder $z = 1 - x^2$ and over the plane region $R$. Find the volume of $D$.

My steps:

First of all, I went to find the area of region R.

Substitute in $x = -1$, $y^2 = 2 - x$

Define in terms of $y$, $x = 2 - y^2$

When $x = 0$, $y = \pm \sqrt{2}$

Integrate:

$\int^\sqrt{2} _{-\sqrt{2}} \sqrt {2 - y^2} dx$

= $[2y - \cfrac{(y)^{3}}{3} + C]^\sqrt{2} _{-\sqrt{2}}$

= $[2\sqrt{2} - \cfrac{2^{1.5}}{3}] - [-2\sqrt{2} - \cfrac{-2^{1.5}}{3}]$

= $4\sqrt{2} - \cfrac{2^{2.5}}{3}$

After this, I'm not sure how I should proceed with finding the region bounded by this area of the plane the parabolic cylinder..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: you don't have to find the area of region $R$ first. As $D$ is the volume under the surface of the form $z=f(x,y)$, we first set the limits of $z$ and then find the projection of the given surface on $xy$-plane that is our region $R$ and then we set the limits of $x, y$.

**HINT:**

The volume of the solid region $D$ can be given by the triple integration as $$V= \int_{y=-\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt{2}} \int_{x=-1}^{1-y^2} \int_{z=0}^{1-x^2} dxdydz$$

i.e. $$V=\int_{y=-\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt{2}} \int_{x=-1}^{1-y^2} (1-x^2) dx dy$$

Comment: Hi so sorry i missed this in my inbox. If i may say your solution in layman -->

first you integrate the parabolic cylinder with respect to region R, using the two equations as the limits.

Then you are integrating with respect to the limits of the parabolic cylinder itself where it touches the axes. 

I can understand the first part and to me it looks like it actually captures the whole volume already. where does the second integral come in?

Comment: Hey! First think about the limits of $z$ that is going from $xy$-plane, i.e. $z=0$ to the surface of parabolic cylinder then you have to take the projection of the parabolic cylinder on the $xy$-plane in the given region $R$ to set the limits of $x$ & $y$. See, when we find volume using triple integral, we are supposed to calculate this: $$Volume=\iiint_{V} dV$$.